# Getting user local setting in Android

Tags: android, timezone

I am creating an application which shows some data on the basis of user country. Currently, I am asking the user to select the country and then storing it. Is there any way, so that the application can get the user local setting from the device and automatically select the corresponding country for the user?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Locale.getDefault()`  should be sufficient for determining the user's preferred locale.  I would need more information on the nature of your data to determine whether it would be proper to use their preferred locale to determine their country, or whether you should be using the GPS/TelephonyManager to get this info.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for more info regarding Locale.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country) for more solutions using TelephonyManager.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it will be sufficient for me to get just the country name.