# Get country name in English from country code

Tags: android, locale

I'd need to get the full country name from the country code.
For example for Netherlands, I'd need `the Netherlands` from the country code `NL`.

I thought I could do that with `Locale` like:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("NL");
loc.getCountry();
```

but `loc.getCountry();` is empty.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can get country code iso from device check this [getNetworkCountryIso()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso())

Comment: I am not sure, but you can use loc.getDisplayCountry()

Comment: @ShreyaShah exactly, it works like that!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

#### Java

```
Locale loc = new Locale("","NL");
loc.getDisplayCountry();
```

#### Kotlin

```
import java.util.Locale
Locale("", "NL").displayCountry
```

Comment: The Locale constructor's above single param version takes first parameter as language and not country code. This did not work in my case. It should be something like this, if country code has to be used.
Locale loc = new Locale("", "NL");

Comment: This worked for me, I just wasted a lot of time thinking whats going wrong with Local(OneParam)....my bad I didnt check the documentation...but thanks for sharing

Answer (score 26):

This should work:

```
Locale l = new Locale("", "NL");
String country = l.getDisplayCountry();
```

The first parameter of Locale is the language, which is not useful in your case.

Comment: if I do this, it retrieves `NL`, so it's not valid

Answer (score 13):

I would like to add more information to the answers above.

If you want to specify language for results, you can use `Locale("your language")` as the parameter of `getDisplayCountry()`.

For example:

```
(new Locale("","NL")).getDisplayCountry(new Locale("ZH"));
```

"ZH" is the language code of Chinese. You will get "荷兰", which is the Chinese name of Netherlands.

And you can use `Locale("languages", "ISO-3166 code")` to specify your language variant.

for example:

```
(new Locale("","NL")).getDisplayCountry(new Locale("ZH", "TW"));
```

`Locale("ZH", "TW")` means the variant of Chinese in Taiwan (traditional Chinese). It has many differences from the Chinese Mainland variant.

You will get "荷蘭", which is the traditional Chinese name of Netherlands.

(Even if you don’t understand Chinese, I think it's obvious that the second Chinese character in the two names is different.)

If you do not specify a language, you will get the name of Netherlands in the device display language, which can be changed in the phone settings. The code is:

```
(new Locale("","NL")).getDisplayCountry();
```

You can get a list of all languages and variants supported by Android [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) :

If you're using kotlin:

```
Locale("", "NL").getDisplayCountry(Locale("ZH"))
Locale("", "NL").getDisplayCountry(Locale("ZH", "TW"))
Locale("", "NL").displayCountry
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the other constructor

```
Locale loc = new Locale("NL", "The Netherlands");
```

[Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)
There does not appear to be a predefined Locale for `The Netherlands`

Comment: but I can't know that `NL` is `the Netherlands`, actually, that's what I wanna get, `the Netherlands` from `NL` :)

Answer (score 0):

for a full solution TelephonyManager (from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872483/reliable-method-to-get-the-country-the-user-is-in)):

```
TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String localeCountry = teleMgr.getNetworkCountryIso();
if (localeCountry != null) {
    Locale loc = new Locale("",localeCountry);
    Log.d(TAG, "User is from " + loc);
}
```

Comment: This returns the current device ISO. That is not what the question is asking for.