# Checking if in-app purchases are supported in user's Google Play country on Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library

I require in-app purchases for certain functionality in my Android App. For users in countries where in-app purchases are not supported I want to make this functionality available for free.

*How can one check if in-app purchases are supported in the user's Google Play country?*

Problems with things I tried:

1. It seems [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042489/determine-play-store-country/25042784#25042784) to determine the Play Store Country.
2. Checking [`BillingClient.BillingResponseCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode) for
   `BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` does not help as this response may also be
   returned if "The Play Store app on the user's device is out of date" or "Google Play is unable to charge the user’s payment method".
3. The `debugMessage` in the `BillingResult` returned by the
   `onBillingSetupFinished` callback of `BillingClient.startConnection`    seems also not helpful as it incorrectly says "Google Play In-app    Billing API version is less than 3" for unsupported countries. (I    tried for China using VPN.)
4. Checking the user's IP address would give wrong results if the user is in a country other than his Play country or uses a VPN.
5. Using location APIs would require location permissions and also give  wrong results if the user is in a foreign country.

Answer (score -1):

In latest version of [Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#dependency) library (5.1). [BILLING_UNAVAILABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode#BILLING_UNAVAILABLE) represents:

> The Play Store app on the user's device is out of date.
>
> The user is in an unsupported country.
>
> The user is an enterprise user and their enterprise admin has disabled
> users from making purchases.
>
> Google Play is unable to charge the user’s payment method.

implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.1.0"

So, I hope this will be helpful for you.

After initializing `billingClient` object, query for starting connection.

```
billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}

    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        val isBillingReady = billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            // Available
        } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE){

            // Make free purchases

        } else {
            // some error needs to be handled
        }
    }
})
```

I have recently developed a [template](https://github.com/epegasus/Google-Plays-Billing) of Google Play Billing V5, you can have a look into that too.

Comment: `onBillingSetupFinished` returns `BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` in unsupported countries. `FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED` seems to be a response code only for `BillingClient.isFeatureSupported`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated answer.

Comment: So this does not help, I already explained the problems with `BILLING_UNAVAILABLE`.