# How to pre-select country code automatically in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

This is my code that receive country code by input(in `onCreate()` method):

```
        countryCodeEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register_country_code_tv);
        countryCodeEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String newCode = s.toString();

                System.out.println("this is new code value "+newCode);
                if (newCode == null || newCode.length() < 1){
                    pickupCountryTv.setText("Choose a country");
                }
                else {
                    if (countryMaps.containsKey(newCode)){
                        countryCode = newCode;
                        countryName = countryMaps.get(newCode);
                        pickupCountryTv.setText(countryName);
                    }
                    else{
                        countryCode = "";
                        countryName = "";
                        pickupCountryTv.setText("Wrong country code");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Now I want to pre-select the country code automatically without input by people. I found the answer using [TelephonyManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country). But I'm confusing of how to set up for my `countryCodeEdt` variable to get the value from this method:

```
public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```

Can someone give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the `getUserCountry` method at your `MainActivity`, define a `String` variable, and call -

```
String countryCode = getUserCountry(getApplicationContext());
```

Now you can use it for your `TextView` -

```
if (countryCode != null) {
   countryCodeEdt.setText(countryName);
} else {
//some error?
}
```

Pay attention that `getUserCountry` returns the **country's code**, not **country's name** i.e. GB and not Great Britain.
You should also handle the case that the SIM card is not presented inside the device.

Comment: Do you mean define `countryCode` inside `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method?

Comment: No. Define it as a seperate method, like `onCreate`, 'onResume` and so on.

Comment: ok I got it, however, `countryCode` always return `null`. I didn't know where the error come from, cause by `getUserCountry` return `null` or due to my device(i used genymotion as a tested device)

Comment: I've tested it with an actuall device and got the correct code.

Comment: Cool, so could you share your simple test on github? I have no actual device right now to test, to make clear what exactly where the error come from.

Comment: I've used exectly your code to get the country code and printed it to the LogCat...