# Android: get device's current language and region(country)

Tags: android, locale

What is the best way to get the current region of the device?
Assume user is in Germany and using Italian as the device's language.
If I use `Locale.getDefault()` then country and language are mapped to each other, i.e. the language is **it** and country is **IT**. What I want is **it** and **DE/GR**(whatever the country code of germany)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where am I? - Get country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country)

Answer (score 2):

Not all locale countries (combinations) are supported in Android, that is why you do not get the country the way you do it now.

You can get the country code using a different method
See for example: [Where am I? - Get country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country)

The second answer shows useful code for you: (Credits to @Marco W.)

```
/**
 * Get ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code for this device (or null if not available)
 * @param context Context reference to get the TelephonyManager instance from
 * @return country code or null
 */
public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```