# Android: Can't get a service running

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I am working on an android app that runs with a **service**. The service will get your location in the background from the simcard. I want to **run** the service **always: every 30 seconds** or something (don't need to be exact) using the alarmmanager. Also when the phone reboots the service needs to be started again.

But **I can't get the service to run**. This is the code I wrote for this problem:

*I added the permissions to the AndroidManifest file:*

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.CountryService" />

<receiver android:name=".broadcasters.CountryUpdateReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I wrote a broadcast receiver that will start the service on boot completed. And I need to add something later that will start the service when you install the app.

*The broadcast receiver called CountryUpdateReceiver:*

```
public class CountryUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CountryService.acquireStaticLock(context);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent countryIntent = new Intent(context, CountryService.class);
        PendingIntent countryService = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, countryIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000, 10 * 1000, countryService);
    }
}
```

*And last I have the service itself called CountryService:*

```
public class CountryService extends WakefulIntentService {

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     */
    public CountryService() {
        super("CountryIntentService");
    }

        @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Service", "Test");
        //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        String country = getUserCountry(this);

        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(CountryProvider.CONTENT_URI + CountryProvider.COUNTRY_ISO_ADD);
        getContentResolver().update(uri2, null, null, new String[] {"BE"});

        //Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("my-event");
        // add data
        //intent.putExtra("message", "data");
        super.onHandleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
    * Get ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code for this device (or null if not available)
    * Origin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country/19415296#19415296
    * @param context Context reference to get the TelephonyManager instance from
    * @return country code or null
    */
    public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
        try {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
            if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
                return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            } else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
                String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
                if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                    return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The service itself extends from `WakefulIntentService` ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/fb7457bed8be9943ce8d.git)). This is a class written by somebody else for getting a wakelock. I followed this [Example](https://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/), because I didn't have any experience with services.

Comment: Have you given permission in manifiest which requires to get location(REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION or REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION)?

Comment: I am getting the location through the simcard so that is something I don't need I think. But nevertheless my service isn't called and the log doesn't show anything so that could be the issue for the service.

Answer (score 1):

Adding following permissions to manifest should help.
These does not seem to added to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Yea I forgot these permissions. I will try it when I am home :)

Comment: That didn't solve my issue :) But thx anyway because It would be a small part of the issue.