# Android get current device coordination or country

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

How to get the phone coordinates or country where is located at the moment in the moment you create your activity ? Tried several methods, but all require a delay/callback and if the device has good performance it returns null most of the time. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get a country code from your configuration like showed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660245/3061577

Probably the best and the most clearest way to get coordinates would be to use GPS location as showed here [How to get current location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Additionaly, if you are using Google Play Services then there's a guide in Android documentation here http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html