# Unity Facebook SDK - Data Policy

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, privacy

We are a developer studio from Germany. We developed an Augmented Reality app with Unity3D. To give the user the possibility to take snapshots within the app and post them on Facebook we are using the Facebook SDK for Unity.

Due to the fact that we developed this for a customer in Germany he has to set up a privacy policy, where he has to ensure that the app **does not send any data** to Facebook **unless the user clicks on the share button**. Our customer asked us as their developers to advise him in this case. The German law is very strict concerning data protection. Especially it says that there should be no communication between the app and the Facebook server before the user explicit allows it (by pressing the share button)

Could you give us any information if the Facebook SDK for Unity is already active while the start of the app or is it only activated, when the user clicks on our share button (which causes an API-Call to `FB.Init()`)?

Comment: Guten tag. Programmer has the answer.  Until FB.Init(), you are safe!  Tschuss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Detect what country the player resides.
2. If in Germany, don't call `FB.Init()` in the beginning of the game. The only time to call is when the player clicks on the Share Button.
3. If not in Germany, use Facebook API as you please.

For Android, you can [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660245/3785314) the country code with such code:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

,or the country name with such code:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

You have to research how to do this on iOS.

**NOTE:** As a big company you want to make sure that the Facebook API is not doing anything else when `FB.Init()` is not called yet. You can easily find out by installing **Wireshack**. Run your app with `FB.Init()` and see if there is a packet going out from your computer to the Facebook server. Then comment `FB.Init()` and check for it again. Just to make sure.

Comment: Hello together, thanks for the fast help! We'll test our app with Wireshark just to be absolutely sure. We hope we can help you guys with a problem someday. Once again: Thank you all! Greetings!

Comment: @RealtimeLabs If the answer helped you, you can accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RealtimeLabs Yes it is. Good luck with your app.