# How to get the Timezone code of an Android device based on its location

Tags: android, timezone, location, utc

I want to get the time zone code of an Android device, not sure how to do it. For example, if the device is located in Auckland, it should return the code NZ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: So the only way is to use latitude and longtitude? How about if current location is turned off? Is there some way I can get it from the settings of the device? I believe user will have to set it the first time when they activate their Android phone.

Comment: Have you read why 3 letter timezone description is depreciated: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country