# Getting current country name

Tags: java, android, iso, telephonymanager

I'm trying to get the country name where the phone is in. For instance if the user is in Germany it has to say Germany. I've tried several things to make this happen, but I haven't found any proper solution. I know I can use `TelephonyManager`, but that will give me the ISO, and I want the name of the country. I've also tried this `getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();`, but that always gives me "United States" even though I'm not there. I know this is possible as I've seen it in another application. Should I use the ISO somehow to accomplish what I what, or is there a smarter/easier way?

Please, don't vote this post as duplicate as I've already searched here on Stackoverflow, but there isn't any solution to get the name of the country :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country

Comment: I've already seen that post, but is the country name recieved? Most of the solutions are how to get the ISO.

Comment: The ISO is a relatively static list, just add it to your app and lookup the full name.

Comment: Where should I look up and how?

Comment: How about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: Or use a prebuilt Java library: https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

Comment: How do I look up when having the ISO code? I've the ISO code and want it to return the "English short name (upper/lower case)"

Answer (score 0):

[Where am I? - Get country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659809/where-am-i-get-country)
gives this code

```
/**
 * Get ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code for this device (or null if not available)
 * @param context Context reference to get the TelephonyManager instance from
 * @return country code or null
 */
public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, wouldn't that be too "deep"? I mean to get the country name. Can't I use the ISO to get the name? `getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();` gave me "United States", I just want it to work properly (if it's possible)

Comment: are you testing `getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCoun‌​try();` on the android emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: It gives me the ISO just with lowercase :(

Comment: `Locale loc = new Locale("","NL");
loc.getDisplayCountry();` @adadudu can get country name from ISO so just call that on ISO

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: @adadudu get the ISO from my method, then create a new Locale object using that string and get it's country by calling `getDisplayCountry()` on that new Locale object initialized with the countries ISO