# How can I use a country boundary geojson file to determine the country of a coordinate?

Tags: android, reversegeocodelocation

I want to have a fast, lightweight and offline method to determine a country from a coordinates. I researched for a long time and found that there is [boundary file in geojson format](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) 
How can I use it in java? thank you

Comment: If you just want the country name, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660245/8244632) can help. It's not based on coordinates but it will provide the country name in which the device is present. Or you can use [this](https://github.com/AReallyGoodName/OfflineReverseGeocode) reverse geocoder [offline], may be helpful.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar, thanks but I do mean any coordinate. For OfflineReverseGeocode, it is overkilled because the overhead is too big (even the cities1000 file) to load in some devices, it also gives approx city which I don't need it

Answer (score 0):

I found [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html) can do the job to test a coordinate if it belongs to a polygon, but the source data are not accurate enough for the world country boundaries.